# currentDate.diff() is not a function error in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```js
const currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); //03/01/2022
var days_diff = currentDate.diff(returnDate,'days'); // returnDate = 08/12/2021

console.log(days_diff)
```

> Error:
> Uncaught TypeError: currentDate.diff is not a function

I am trying to get the days difference between the current date and the return date but it is giving me an error currentDate.diff is not a function

Please solve this error.

Comment: isn't the `currentDate` variable a string after your formatting? You should do all the math that you want first and do the formatting at the end. If that is not possible, then re-convert it back to the `Date` object, do the math and then format it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.format('DD/MM/YYYY')` outputs a string, which is not going to have the Moment functions available to it. Instead do this:

```
const currentDate = moment(new Date('03/01/2022'));
const returnDate = moment(new Date('08/12/2021'));
var days_diff = currentDate.diff(returnDate,'days');

console.log(days_diff)
```

Maintain the Moment Date object throughout your operations. Formatting it early just makes it a string.